# Using Matplotlib with Dask

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dask, dask-dataframe

Let's say we have pandas dataframe `pd` and a dask dataframe `dd`. When I want to plot pandas one with matplotlib I can easily do it:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(pd["series1"], pd["series2"])
fig.savefig(path)
```

However, when I am trying to do the same with dask dataframe I am getting `Type Errors` such as:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'string[python]' as a data type
```

`string[python]` is just an example, whatever is your `dd["series1"]` datatype will be inputed here.

So my question is: What is the proper way to use `matplotlib` with `dask`, and is this even a good idea to combine the two libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SultanOrazbayev's is still spot on, here is an answer elaborating on the `datashader` option (which `hvplot` call under the hood).

### Don't use Matplotlib, use [hvPlot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/)!

If you wish to plot the data while it's still large, I recommend using hvPlot, as it can natively handle dask dataframes. It also automatically **provides interactivity**.

#### Example

```py
import numpy as np
import dask
import hvplot.dask

# Create Dask DataFrame with normally distributed data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
df['x'] = df['x'].map_partitions(lambda x: np.random.randn(len(x)))
df['y'] = df['y'].map_partitions(lambda x: np.random.randn(len(x)))

# Plot
df.hvplot.scatter(x='x', y='y', rasterize=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One motivation to use `dask` instead of `pandas` is the size of the data. As such, swapping `pandas` DataFrame with `dask` DataFrame might not be feasible. Imagine a scatter plot, this might work well with 10K points, but if the dask dataframe is a billion rows, a plain `matplotlib` scatter is probably a bad idea (`datashader` is a more appropriate tool).

Some graphical representations are less sensitive to the size of the data, e.g. normalized bar chart should work well, as long as the number of categories does not scale with the data. In this case the easiest solution is to use `dask` to compute the statistics of interest before plotting them using `pandas`.

To summarise: I would consider the nature of the chart, figure out the best tool/representation, and if it's something that can/should be done with `matplotlib`, then I would run computations on `dask` DataFrame to get the reduced result as a `pandas` dataframe and proceed with the `matplotlib`

Comment: My size of the data doesn't let me use pandas, at leats on my computer (11+gb of gzip csv files). So after I extract the data with dask I should convert it to pandas and then try to plot it? I think that my plots are appropriate for the size of the data.

Comment: Yes, if by 'convert it to pandas' you mean some procedure to reduce the dataset, e.g. let's say you have 10 categories X and 1 billion rows of some variable Y. Then I would run something like `stats = df.groupby('X').agg({'Y': 'mean'}).compute()`, and then `stats` will be a pandas dataframe that can be used as usual with matplotlib. The specific aggregation procedure will depend on questions of interest.